# LCD screen pixel problem

Tags: display

First, my laptop screen pixels are okay. No dead pixels or stuck pixels.

It just happens to annoy me recently. Some of the pixels on the screen (quite a lot of them) become randomly colored after being stationary for merely 10 mins. But if you refresh the screen, those malfunctioning pixels are gone. I can replicate this again and again, but I am not sure if the screen is going to be broken or something. I just bought the laptop 4 months ago.

Comment: Can you capture this on a screenshot and post the screenshot in your question?

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh the screen"? Change the picture displayed? @Thomas I don't think you can make a screenshot of that :P

Comment: I haven't been able to capture the screenshot the show the defects. I really thinks its the screen's problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the laptop is still under warranty, I would see about getting a new laptop.  Sounds to me like the screen is defective.  There is no reason why the laptop screen should be doing that... especially after only four months of use.

Comment: I also wouldn't worry too much about fixing this yourself. Just take it back to the dealer and show him the defect.